# Async Task: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am getting the following  `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` when trying to get the new instance of a 
*classObject*.getNewInstance().

**Everything I have read involved altering the UI thread. Is that the case here? If so, how to I get around this exception?**

Code ([Example used](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-java-method-at-runtime/)):

```
public class MainActivityAsyncClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        postData(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

    public void postData(String methodToRun) {
        Class[] noParams = {};
        try {
            Class mainActivityClass = Class.forName("com.MainActivity");
            Method asyncRun = mainActivityClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodToRun, noParams);
            Object obj = mainActivityClass.newInstance(); //<-- Error is thrown here
            asyncRun.invoke(obj, null);
        } catch(Exception e){
            Util.appendLog("Error in async task. Exception: " + e.getMessage() + " " + e.getStackTrace());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: First of all you should never create instance of activity dervied class from your code...

Comment: Go back a few steps: what do you want to achieve? I am sure there are better ways to do it.

Comment: Agree with @Henry. Looks like you are trying to execute some method from your main activity on a separate thread? Even if you want to do this, I would move that logic to another class and use interface/implementation to define the method that you really want to invoke instead of dynamically figuring out what needs to be invoked. If you want the main activity to be updated because of whatever you execute, use onPostExecute to do it.

Comment: Thank you all for the advice! I looked over the objectives and found a better way to do this

Answer (score 0):

in an AsyncTask :

doInBackground - invoked on background Thread, used to perform background computation.

onPostExecute - Invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes.All UI updates/Launching New Activity must be done on onPostExecute function of AsyncTask.

Refer the following [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Add the following to your AsyncTask to make it work :

```
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     postData(methodToRun);
 }
```

methodToRun can be a member variable